# Use Class<?> parameter in instanceof method

Tags: java, casting, instanceof, java-15

I have the following method that can return different types of Storable (ex: Food, Ore).

*Inventory.java*

```
public Storable get(Class<? extends Storable> cls) {
    for (Storable storable : inventory) {
        if(cls.isInstance(storable)) {
            this.inventory.remove(storable);
            return storable;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It works, however I'm forced to cast my result like below:

```
Food food = (Food) inventory.get(Food.class);
```

With Java 15 and above, we can define casted object directly with `instanceof` ([link to javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html)). I'm wondering if I can use this new syntax and return casted object directly.

I tried this but `instanceof` keyword only works with type not variable:

```
public Storable get(Class<? extends Storable> cls) {
    for (Storable storable : inventory) {
        if(storable instanceof cls castedItem) {  //cls cannot be resolved to a type
            this.inventory.remove(storable);
            return castedItem;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Use a generic type on the method itself: `public <T extends Storable> T get(Class<T> cls) { ... }`. No need for any Java 15 features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make your method generic:

```
public <S extends Storable> S get(Class<S> cls) {
    for (Storable storable : inventory) {
        if (cls.isInstance(storable)) {
            this.inventory.remove(storable);
            return cls.cast(storable);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note the use of `cls.cast`. That's like `(S) storable` but without the compiler warning.